# How do I format data for each row fetched? (Codeigniter, My_Model)

Tags: php, codeigniter, date-formatting

I have a table called events and I'm storing the **start** date in the **datetime** format.

However, I'm using a [plugin](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) that the requires the dates are formatted to: 
`YYYY-MM-DD`.

I would, therefore, only like to select part of the datetime but without modifying the underling table structure. Is there a way to format the field data for each record as it is being fetched? The reason I ask is because it seems inefficient to go through each record again (like I am at the moment) and format one field.

```
$this->load->model('event_model');
$events = $this->event_model->get_all();

foreach ($events as $event) {
    $start = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($event->start));
    //add event to new event array     
}

$output = json_encode($events); // I would like to use the formatted date when using json_encode on $events.
```

I'm using [codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter) with [My Model](https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why you dont just stored to your generated model?

for example:

```
$this->load->model("event_model");
$events = $this->event_model->get_all();

foreach($events as $event){
  $event->mydate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($event->start));
}
```

now pass your $events to the view and use mydate property.

Comment: Like the answer. I've updated my question to include something I missed out.

Comment: if you want to use start property then change `$event->mydate` with `$event->start` in my loop. Then all `$events` will have the `start` property formated.

Answer (score 1):

Simply format your date in your sql code

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *,  FORMAT(start,'YYYY-MM-DD') as eventStart
FROM events
```

Format it in the query itself.